# read a large text file on server and display them on web page

Tags: javascript, html, file, web, cgi

I have a text file of 200mb - 400 mb. I wanted to see these files on my web site. When I try to read this file using cgi script, the website becomes unresponsive. I tried reading the file in chunks but could not succeed. How should I accomplish this task. I am new to web technologies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way to resolve your issue is to implement pagination so you could get pages of book pages (pun not intended), if the book you have is stored on the backend.

If it is stored on the client computer - are you sure that you need this? There might be some other ways to resolve the problem you are facing, yet loading a 200-400mb file onto the browser is really a bad idea.

Comment: Those files are not books. They are logs of my system(plain text files). What is the best possible approach to be used for pagination of text files.

Comment: It depends on the how the log is structured. You could implement a simple pagination by line count. I.E. url.com/log?skip=0&take=100 would retrieve first 100 lines. Maybe the log has more difficult structure like each item in the log is separated by a line of asterisks, then you could parse it as a log item and return a desired number of items, skippin n items.

Comment: Thanks. This approach worked for me. I am reading the file line by line in chunks.